# Java: use timer thread to determin the behavior in the parent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, timer

I am writing code in java and I am making a request from another system. I want that if I won't get a response while I am counting (parallel), I will call send error function or throw exception to be catched in the main thread

```
try {
   StartTimer();
   result = request.ExecuteOperation();
   sendSuccess(result);
} 
catch (MyExeption ex) {
   handleExeption(ex!= null? ex.getMessage(): "General Exeption", ex, systemID)
}
```

How does `StartTimer()` count 2 minutes and check if `ExecuteOperation()` returned and if 2 minutes have passed to throw MyException that will be caught in the main thread?

Comment: Have you tried to explore Java Thread: notify() and wait() instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, many blocking API calls have a timeout parameter that you may be able to use.

If not, I would turn this around and do the `executeOperation` bit on a background thread, wrapped in a Future.

The current thread can then call `get` on the Future with a timeout specified.

```
Future<MyResult> futureResult = executor.submit(new Callable<MyResult>(){
   void call(){
       return request.ExecuteOperation();
   }
});
return futureResult.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CountDownLatch`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit). Something like:

```
public class Test {

    public void executeOperation(CountDownLatch latch ) {
        // runs on separate thread and perform the operation
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        test.executeOperation(latch);
        if (!latch.await(2, MINUTES)) {
            // report an error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this function waits untli the count reach 0. i want the excecution to run while counting and if :the counting ends before the proccecing send error; else: all good countinue the program;